# Why am I unable to grab all 4 matchdata from Regexp?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a function that is suppose to grab 4 sets of 8 binary numbers in order to convert it into an IP address. I have this regexp to do so:

```
def convert_to_decimal(binary_string)
  octet1,octet2,octet3,octet4 = /(\d{8})/.match(binary_string).captures
  puts octet1
  puts octet2
  puts octet3
  puts octet4
end
```

I've tested this regex in rubular and it confirms that it grabs 4 matches when I test it with a string 10000000001000000000101000000001. However when I run the actually ruby code, I only get the first set of 8 numbers. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan) instead:

```
def convert_to_decimal(binary_string)
  octet1,octet2,octet3,octet4 = binary_string.scan /\d{8}/
  puts octet1
  puts octet2
  puts octet3
  puts octet4
end

convert_to_decimal('10000000001000000000101000000001')
```

output:

```
10000000
00100000
00001010
00000001
```

---

If you want to use [`MatchData#captures`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/MatchData.html#method-i-captures), modify the regular expression to contain four captured groups because `MatchData#captures` returns an array of captured groups not matches :

```
octet1,octet2,octet3,octet4 =
  /(\d{8})(\d{8})(\d{8})(\d{8})/.match(binary_string).captures
```